# How to use fit property of projection?

Tags: vega

I assigned a geojson object to the fit property of the projection as described in the documentation: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/projections/

I am always getting the error "Unsupported parameter object: {"type": "FeatureCollection"..."

I am assigning the geojson object as following: (my source data is topojson format)

```
  spec.projections[0].fit = topojson.feature(
    mapData,
    mapData.objects.topology
  );
```

The documentation explicitly says that this parameter should be a GeoJSON Feature or FeatureCollection. How am I supposed to use the fit property?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a reference to a data object.

```
"data": [
  {
    "name": "counties",
    "url": "data/us-10m.json",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "counties" }
  }
],
"projections": [
  {
    "name": "projection",
    "type": "mercator",
    "fit": {"signal": "data('counties')"},
    "size": {"signal": "[width, height]"}
  }
]
```

Here is an example from VEGA that you can test in their edit.
https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/master/test/specs-valid/map-fit.vg.json

Also notice the "size" property. The fit does not get reflected without it.